# Cannot do a post request using fopen

Tags: php, http, post, request, fopen

I'm trying to do a post request using fopen but I cannot change headers for request and cannot complete it. I need help please see my code:

```
$data_array = array(
   'MerchantOrderId'=>'2014111703',
   'Customer'=>array(  
      'Name'=>'Comprador Teste'     
   ),
   'Payment'=>array(  
     'Type'=>'CreditCard',
     'Amount'=> '100',
     'Provider'=>'Simulado',
     'Installments'=>1,
     'CreditCard'=>array(  
         'CardNumber'=>'4461561220666711',
         'Holder'=>'Pablo Pablo',
         'ExpirationDate'=>'01/2019',
         'SecurityCode'=>'101',
         'Brand'=>'Master'
     )
   )
);

$data = json_encode($data_array);

$header = 'Content-Type : application/json\r\n'.
          'Content-Length :'. strlen($data).'\r\n'.
          'MerchantId : 3a361c55-2feb-4c8d-a0e9-1cf24fb31242\r\n'.
          'MerchantKey : VXXIKMBOZHBZACKKJHHTYLECTACKIYQXAXYHOJNI\r\n'.
          'RequestId : 4e361c55-2feb-4c8d-a0e9-1cf24fb31244';

$context_opt = array(
    'https' => array (
        'method'  => "POST",
    'header'  => $header,
    'content' => $data
    )
);

$url = 'https://apisandbox.braspag.com.br/v2/sales';

$fp = fopen(
  $url, 
  'r', 
  false, 
  stream_context_create($context_opt)
);

if (!$fp)
{
    throw new Exception('Problem with $url, $php_errormsg');
}

$result = stream_get_contents($fp);

fclose($fp);

print_r($result);
```

I tested this config using rest console chrome extension and worked fine
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The `header` argument should, I think, be an array rather than a string for the context

Comment: I would advise you remove the MerchantID and MerchantKey from your question if they are real, and put some random values. Also the credit card details (which I hope are not real!)

Answer (score 1):

In your context options array you need to use the key `http`, not `https`.  https is not it's own wrapper, it's the http wrapper + the ssl wrapper combined.

```
$context_opt = array(
    'http' => array (
        'method'  => "POST",
        'header'  => $header,
        'content' => $data
    )
);
```

In addition to that, you need to fix your headers definition.  First you need to use double-quoted strings in order for the `\r\n` escapes to create new lines.  With single quotes you'll get a literal `'\r\n'` separating the headers.  Second you need to remove the space between the header name and the colon, spaces are not permitted in the header name.

```
$header = "Content-Type: application/json\r\n".
          "Content-Length: ". strlen($data)."\r\n".
          "MerchantId: 3a361c55-2feb-4c8d-a0e9-1cf24fb31242\r\n".
          "MerchantKey: VXXIKMBOZHBZACKKJHHTYLECTACKIYQXAXYHOJNI\r\n".
          "RequestId: 4e361c55-2feb-4c8d-a0e9-1cf24fb31244";
```